# Should Copper 65 and Copper 63 isotopes have a larger density than a copper 29 atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, density, radioactivity, isotopes

I was looking at the first page of a paper (see https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1735598#Metrics-content for details) and I ran across something odd. According to the paper, Copper isotopes 63 and 65 had much lower densities than the stable copper 29 atom. Moreover, Copper 65 had a density of 7.17 while copper 63 had a density of 7.93. Unfortunately, since I do not have a membership to the website I was only able to read the first page, which prevented me from finding out whether the source of this anomaly was human error or nature. I was wondering how this is possible since according to current atomic theory these isotopes should have a much larger nucleus than Copper 29.

Comment: What do you mean by copper 29? That would indicate copper with 29 protons and no neutrons, which doesn't exist as an isotope.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why were you looking up data for copper isotope densities? Is it related to your research?

Comment: David- 29 is the copper's atomic number. But since I did use 65 and 63 to describe the copper isotopes, I should have probably used copper 58 to describe normal copper.

Comment: Perhaps take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_copper 58Cu is unstable with a half life of 3.204(7) seconds. For heavy atoms an excess of neutrons over protons is required for stability.

Comment: I took a look at that my2cts, and that helped a lot. Also IAmAStudent, the reason why I was looking at the densities is that I was looking into gravitational anomalies with radioactivity.

Comment: @Anthony Ducharme, do you mean looking for gravitational anomalies caused by radioactive isotopes in Earth's crust?

Comment: @IAmAStudent- No, not in the earth's crust. Rather, I am looking to see how isotopes affect the gravity surrounding it. I've only just begun, but I've found some interesting things. For example, Tritium oxide has a density of 1.85 while deuterium oxide and regular water (H2O) have densities of 1.11 and .997. The only difference that exists between T2O and D2O/H2O is the fact that T2O is radioactive while D2O/H2O are not. Therefore, this oddity in density, at least to me, seems to result from radioactivity. This may not have much to do with gravity per say, but it is still interesting.

Comment: @Anthony Ducharme, well, the difference is the number of neutrons, no? Ah, I see things dont scale ratiometrically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it says in the paper

> The discrepancy between the isotopically
>   enriched samples and the cited value for natural copper [$8.93\, g/\text{cm}^3$]
>   was thought to be due to trapped gases. Consequently, some of
>   each sample was vacuum melted in an effort to reduce this
>   trapping.

After taking measures to reduce the gas trapping, and taking account of chemical and isotope impurities, the paper reports $8.83\pm 0.05\, g/\text{cm}^3$ for Cu-63 and $9.12\pm 0.05\, g/\text{cm}^3$ for Cu-65, in Table I of the paper. These corrected values are in excellent agreement with densities calculated (not measured) using crystallography and isotopic data.

Comment: How did you get that information? Are you by any chance a member of the website?

Comment: I am a university student so I have access to most journals....